# Replace with like

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have an ms sql table with `brief_n` as a column which holds records like this

`xx/xx/xx: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed di`
where xx/xx/xx is the corresponding date. How do I get rid of all the date and just have 
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed di`.

I am not sure what goes into the replace field.

```
UPDATE tablename.dbo.news
SET brief_n = REPLACE (brief_n,'','')
WHERE brief_n LIKE '--/--/--'
```

Comment: so is xx/xx/xx is stored as 12/10/67: ? is your format fixed?

Comment: yes the format is fixed all the fields have xx/xx/xx: as the initial letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE tablename.dbo.news
SET brief_n = substring(brief_n,10,4000)
WHERE brief_n LIKE '__/__/__:%'
```

Explanation: Truncate first 10 chars for all rows starting with `'__/__/__:'`.

Comment: This worked perfect. :-) so is using replace wrong in this case ?

Comment: Replace is intended to change a string by other. In this scenario, substring is more clear, also 'right': `right( brief_n, len(brief_n)-10)` . Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

if all the string is in the same format as u said u can use substring

substring(brief_n,11, len(brief_n))

Hope it helps.